# Backend Deveopment practice project

Tags: python, django, rest, version-control, backend

How can we create a project that can be used to store notes which can be textual, audio or
video. Where the system can have many users who can share notes amongst them.Should create a backend project for pratacticing the fucntional REST apis. The database can be sqlite for testing the api
functionality.The major functionality i need is to store the notes and query the stored notes.

I have been trying to do build a project and need some ideas which will help me to prepare a better product